# scan -> nav -> motors?

Tags: motor, navigation, ros2

I built a 2 wheels robot, and I can control the wheels through GPIO on a RPI4 8gb

I can launch a couple of TF transformations, launch the lidar, navigation and the rviz the result by launching these commands in different terminals

```
ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom
ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_footprint
ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 odom base_link
ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser
ros2 launch sllidar_ros2 sllidar_a1_launch.py
ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation_launch.py
ros2 launch slam_toolbox online_async_launch.py
```

then I wrote a service to controll the motors with GPIO and provide sensors data to the navigation system
but as I read the doc, willing to have the nav2_bringup to talk to my service, I feel

I am going the wrong way
it looks incredibly difficult to do such a simple thing with ROS
I am confused and need help from more experienced users

thanks

Comment: Hi Phil, Please try to break down your problems into smaller answerable questions. Large open ended requests for help are not a good match for this forum. Your challenges are spanning multiple large complex systems from transforms to sensor pipelines to navigation stack configuration. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: In particular I recommend that you break things down into smaller more reproducible elements. You're configuring a lot of moving parts that I don't think you understand which is why you're having a cognative disconnect with "do such a simple thing" when you're deploying systems that have the aggregate work of many PhD theses. You probably also want to start with some examples which are fully configured for you such as the TurtleBot in simulation to learn how the system works before trying to implement it from scratch yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am reading Rico's book(*) although compiling the book project fails on ubuntu 20.04 VM while works on a raspbery pi

but RPI is too slow to run gazebo

(*) A Concise Introduction to Robot Programming with ROS2

Comment: "Rico's book"...? Do you mean *A Concise Introduction to Robot Programming with ROS2*? If so, then it might be best to explicitly state the name of the book for those who are not as well versed in the literature. If not, then (again), please [edit] and state the title of the book to which you are referring. Nevertheless, is the answer to your issue simply that *the Pi 4 is not powerful enough*?

Answer (score 1):

The TFs you're publishing show you have some confusion about what different parts of ROS2 will do for you.  The tutorials are generally good and as noted by Tully, you should take the time to go through them. There is really no substitute for the tutorials. If I explained to you why publishing a static transform for ODOM to BASELINK didn't make any sense, you would get stuck on the reason that MAP to ODOM doesn't make sense.  There is a very good tutorial on how to set up a robot with ROS. I'm not sure one exists with ROS2 but all the concepts will carry from ROS into ROS2.

ROS(2) is a huge thing as Tully explained. It will take you significant time for things to start making sense, and those of us further along the learning curve understand that ***the tutorials will be MUCH FASTER than asking the forum*** for help on the easy stuff like TFs.

Comment: I followed the tutorials, I started from there, I added th TF's as I had errors about them

Comment: You should go back to the point where you started having problems and work through those issues instead of publishing TFs that short circuit most of the ROS logic you're implementing. What tutorial were you following? Can you share link>